# Align CSS content

Tags: css

I have the following panel:
[image: panel]

And what I want is to centralize the circle charts inside the `td` of my table and keep it centralized when it turns to mobile. I'm having some issues trying to do that. This is how my code is:

```
<div class="portlet-body row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="nome-rv"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?=$_SESSION['nomeCompleto']?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered tabela-meta">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="grafico-situacao">
                        <div class="c100 p100 orange big">
                            <span>100%</span>
                            <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>                     
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PISO</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered tabela-meta">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="grafico-situacao">
                        <div class="c100 p82 big">
                            <span>82%</span>
                            <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>META</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered tabela-meta">                        
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="grafico-situacao">
                        <div class="c100 p63 green big">
                            <span>63%</span>
                            <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SUPERMETA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are some classes but I'm not using them by now.

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apNrxy

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: is that bootstrap then? you should set up a jsfiddle or codepen or something that would illustrate the issue.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to include the CSS which applies to the circle charts. Also, you say "keep it centralized when it turns to mobile" - do you mean it works in a desktop browser?

Comment: @AndrewMorton what do you mean by the css i have forgotten? And yes! Its a responsive layout, and I said that because the only way I could 'centralize' it was using left: 33% and right: 33%, but when it turns to mobile, is not centralized anymore.

Comment: Make a working fiddle and we will help you achieve the desired result.

Comment: @jvbarsou we cannot reproduce what is in the screenshot with the provided code. There is some CSS that you have not provided that would do this. Questions are expected to contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @sweaver2112 link at my question

Comment: @jvbarsou You have `class = "grafico-situacao"` etc. but we cannot see the CSS rules for those classes unless you edit your question to show them.

Comment: Centered them vertically or horizontally ?? http://i.imgur.com/wt62xwT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to do if you can leverage flexbox (See browser compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)).

If you're using Bootstrap version 4, you can just wrap the content with:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">...</div>
```

See the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#justify-content) for more information.

If you're using Bootstrap version 3, you can still use the flexbox styles directly:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS to this

```
.c100 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 120px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 0 auto 0.1em auto; /* margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0; */
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```